# Mac OS X daemon using Objective-C -  launchd

Tags: objective-c, macos, launchd, launch-daemon

I'm new in Mac OS X world but I have skills on Windows dev.

I need to develop a daemon (on Windows will be Windows Service) that uploads/downloads files from a Web Service.

**My question is:** is it possible to create an app written in Objective-C that will be the daemon (to upload/download) and to launch it when the OS starts using launchd? Or there's another way to create a daemon?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I have understood correctly but I guess you can do it. The next link could be a good start for understand how Daemons work in Objective-C
[Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2005/tn2083.html)
Then here there is a interesting piece of code. [It is about GPS but it might be usefull](http://chrisalvares.com/blog/?p=7). Also get a look of this github folder.[It is a controller for start/stop daemons](https://github.com/ivanvc/DaemonController)

Comment: Thank you, that's something that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

On OS X these services are called LaunchDaemon (system-wide) and LaunchAgent (user-specific). You create a configuration which tells the system when to start, which executable to run, what to do with stdin, stdout, and stderr, which arguments to pass, and so on. Have a look at these man pages:

```
launchd(8)       # the service controlling other services
launchctl(1)     # the command to control services
launchd.plist(5) # the configuration format for services
```

The daemon can be written in any language that runs on OS X. So Objective-C is a typical choice for the Mac platform, but anything else from Ruby, Python, and Perl over AppleScript to plain C or C++ would do.

And no, there is no other (recommended) way to do this on the Mac. `init.d`-style scripts don't work on the Mac [or on Darwin, it's UNIX layer]. Or, more precisely, there is not the infrastructure that runs them.

For more info see the [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html).

Comment: Emphasis: ***can*** be written in any language.  Should not use Obj-C for a LaunchDaemon or system-level LaunchAgent because of InputManager hacks!